# Linear regression on circulant matrices

Tags: regression, linear, ridge-regression, fourier-transform

I am reading the paper on [High-Speed Tracking with Kernelized Correlation Filters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7584)
 and I am a bit stuck on the equivalence of Ridge regression in the frequency domain. Minimizing the typical equation for Ridge regression is

$$\min_\textbf{w} \sum_i \left ( \textbf{w}^T\textbf{x} - y_i\right ) ^2 + \lambda ||\textbf{w}||^2$$

This can be solved with the closed form solution

$$\textbf{w} = \left ( \textbf{X}^T \textbf{X} + \lambda \textbf{I}\right )^{-1} \textbf{X}^T \textbf{y}$$

When $\textbf{X}$ is circulant, this can be computed faster in the frequency domain with

$$\hat{\textbf{w}} = \frac{\hat{\textbf{x}}^* \odot \hat{\textbf{y}}}{\hat{\textbf{x}}^* \odot \hat{\textbf{x}} + \lambda}$$

where $\hat{\textbf{x}}$ denotes $\textbf{x}$ in the frequency domain and $\textbf{x}^*$ denotes the conjugate.

This is all very nice, but when I try to implement this in numpy, I get different results for both methods:

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize the generating vector
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
# Initialize the permutation matrix
P = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
])

# Form the circulant matrix using the generating vector
X = np.vstack((np.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(P, i), x) for i in range(len(x))))

# Set the regularization coefficient
alpha = 1

# Solve closed form solution
w_spatial = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X) + np.eye(len(x)) * alpha).dot(X.T).dot(y)
# array([3.35521303e-02, 4.39547559e-04, 4.39547559e-04, 3.35521303e-02,
   9.27591865e-01])

# Solve in frequency domain
x_freq = np.fft.fft(x) / np.sqrt(5)
y_freq = np.fft.fft(y) / np.sqrt(5)
w_freq = (np.conj(x_freq) * y_freq) / (np.conj(x_freq) * x_freq + alpha)
w_fft = np.real(np.fft.ifft(w_freq)) * np.sqrt(5)
# array([-0.78218188,  0.64077047,  0.84404937,  0.84404937,  0.64077047])
```

Clearly, my results don't match up, and I'm not certain why... The `np.sqrt(5)` is there because the paper mentions unitary FFT and to correct for it by a factor of $\sqrt{n}$, but removing it doesn't make the results match either.

I must be missing some key part that I can't figure out. Any help would be appreciated.